# ProcessMaker import groups from FreeIPA

Tags: freeipa

I just connected ProcessMaker to FreeIPA using advanced LDAP authentication using [this tutorial](http://www.processmaker.com/bpm-ldap-and-bpm-active-directory) and I was able to import users list and login using FreeIPA accounts.
My problem is that I can't synchronize groups, when I click on its button I get an empty window. I even waited for several minutes for it to load with no luck.
can anyone help me to enable group synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logs to see what queries PM issues in this case. It may well be that the schema expectations are different or it uses wrong filter or base DN.

Comment: The processMaker is sending a filter "(&(objectCategory=group)(name=*))", although freeipa doesn't have an objectCategory. How can I solve that?

Comment: From processMaker documentation you pointed to it is not clear if there is any way to redefine group-related query. I'd suggest filing a bug with processMaker and persuade them to add a profile that covers normal way to detect groups in LDAP servers utilizing RFC 4519 with (&(objectclass=GroupOfNames)(cn=*)) filter.